# Unconstrained type in trait despite it being used in trait bounds?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have this snippet:

```rs
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::ops::Index;
use len_trait::Len;

pub trait Container : Default + Debug + Clone
{
    type IndexingType;
    type ValueType: Default + Clone;

    fn len(&self) -> usize;
    fn get(&self, i: &Self::IndexingType) -> Self::ValueType;
    fn indexing_iterator(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Self::IndexingType>;
}

impl<C, I, V> Container for C
    where C: Index<I, Output = V> + Len + IntoIterator<Item = V> + Debug + Default + Clone,
{
    type IndexingType = I;
    type ValueType = V;

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len()
    }

    fn get(&self, i: &Self::IndexingType) -> Self::ValueType {
        self[i]
    }

    fn indexing_iterator(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=Self::IndexingType> {
        self.indexing_iterator()
    }
}
```

Which is yielding this error

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `I` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/traits.rs:15:9
   |
15 | impl<C, I, V> Container for C
   |         ^ unconstrained type parameter

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0207`.
```

I don't understand why. The generic type is being used in the trait bounds, why doe sthe compiler claim it is unrestricted?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler’s error message could be clearer, but essentially it's saying that you're trying to use an associated type to implement a family of `Container` traits for `C`, when you should be using a generic trait parameter on `Container`.

When using an associated type, you're saying that the trait can only be implemented once for the implementing type, and that at that moment the associated type must be chosen to be a single type. An example is `Deref<Target=Whatever>`; you can only implement `Deref` once per type, and at that moment its `Target` must be fixed as one concrete type.

On the other hand, generic trait parameters instead create a family of traits, each member of which can be implemented for a given type. An example is `Add<Rhs>`; you can implement `Add<T> for MyType` as many times as you'd like with a different `T` each time.

So all you have to do is replace `Container`’s associated type with a generic parameter. (Below, I've removed references to `Len` and added the necessary trait bounds to `V`.)

```rust
pub trait Container<IndexingType>: Default + Debug + Clone {
    type ValueType: Default + Clone;

    fn len(&self) -> usize;
    fn get(&self, i: &IndexingType) -> Self::ValueType;
    fn indexing_iterator(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = IndexingType>;
}

impl<C, I, V> Container<I> for C
where
    C: Index<I, Output = V> + IntoIterator<Item = V> + Debug + Default + Clone,
    V: Default + Clone,
{
    type ValueType = V;

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len()
    }

    fn get(&self, i: &I) -> Self::ValueType {
        self[i]
    }

    fn indexing_iterator(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = I> {
        self.indexing_iterator()
    }
}
```

There are some other compiler errors here, but they're no longer material to the issue of how to declare the trait.